# How to understand the structure "And protect them she did:＂?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, colons

A quote from ACT english test passage:

> **And protect them she did:** When workers went on strike, Jones secured food donations and temporary living arrangements. Where companies prevented the formation of unions, she fought for workers’ right to organize.

For starters, I am totally confused by the grammatical structure of the bold text, not like inversion or imperative and with two verbs not in aggreement with tense.

Furthermore, I think colon can only be used when the former sentence is complete; in this case, however, "she did" is obviously imcomplete: she did what? So I figure colon is imappropriate here.

Any explaination is sincerely appreciated !

Comment: "She said she would protect them, **and protect them she did**" is a common construction in this form. It's for emphasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inverted sentence structure](https://www.thoughtco.com/inversion-definition-1209968) is used here. Often, to emphasize a point, this is done, as well as in question. For example:

```
Kick the ball? Right past the goalie, he kicked it!

He is going home. [statement] -> Is he going home? [query]
```